# How to load a large table in a mysql docker container without blocking the database?

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-entrypoint

I use the default [mysql docker container](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/). I have a 500Mb (compressed sql.gz file) table backup which takes a long time  to load. My current option is to load this large table in the background after the container is started.
I have tried to place the large table sql.gz file in `docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` but then I am unable to access the database after container startup. I waited more than 20 minutes and am still not able to access the database in that container. If I remove that large sql.gz file from `docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`, I can access the database right after container start, no problem.

- What is the recommended way of loading large tables in a MySQL docker container?

Comment: Is this a production or development environment? Most of the database containers suggest using a volume to persist your data. Perhaps that is an option?

Comment: It is a production environment (currently experimental), on a cloud server. volume were not an option for me -  At least not a straightforward option - because I wanted to store the database dumps on an external drive, purchased separately and mounted .

Comment: Loading database dumps tend to take a while, but depending on how frequently you reload the data it is typically acceptable.